# How would this be written correctly?

Tags: c#

These If statements i just realized are completley wrong.
I only need to call the RevokeAssignments() Method or the RevokeQueues() Method if there was a chkbx.CheckedChanged. So basically if you change the status of a check box, checked or unchecked It would recognize which ones were checked and are not anymore and then call these methods.

It's a C# Program, WINFORM in VS2013.. **THANKS IN ADVANCE**

So, **How would the code be written that would correctly call these methods? Do i have to write an if statement for every possible change?** because that seems redundant.

```
       if (chkbxConsolepld.Checked == true || chkbxDFwov.Checked == true || chkbxFloorMat.Checked == true || chkbxGeopointeAd.Checked == true
            || chkbxGeopointeBP.Checked == true || chkbxJobCC.Checked == true || chkbxNewJob.Checked == true || chkbxPOPro.Checked == true
            || chkbxReportEd.Checked == true || chkbxSalesAccQ.Checked == true || chkbxServMax.Checked == true || chkbxWordOrdDel.Checked == true)
        {
            RevokeAssignments();
        }
        if (chkbxAtlanta.Checked == true || chkbxDallas.Checked == true || chkbxDallasCC.Checked == true
            || chkSouthernCities.Checked == true || chkbxPending.Checked == true || chkbxClosedCanc.Checked == true)
        {
            RevokeQueues();
        }
```

Comment: You probably want to subscribe to the checkbox's Changed event or what have you, and call your methods when it fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one event handler for multiple controls.

For the first group you're checking the value set `CheckedChanged` event to the first handler that will call RevokeAssignments() and for the second group create a second handler, that will perform RevokeQueues().